# What caused Irwin Allen to change theme songs for Lost in Space?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-1965, theme-music, john-williams

The 1960's TV series [had two theme songs](https://youtu.be/712ns4jnG-k), both by John Williams. The first one, with the great tuba riff, was used for the first two seasons, but for some reason a new theme was used for the third season before the show was cancelled.

The ultimate decision to change the theme song this would have gone through producer Irwin Allen.

I guess we shouldn't complain, because we got another memorable TV theme song out of it. But I'm curious as to why Allen decided to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Starlog #219](https://archive.org/stream/starlog_magazine-219/219_djvu.txt), the show was dramatically retooled for its third season. Rather than spending an episode in space, then crash-landing on a planet where they would spend the remainder of the series, the third season was intended to be a showcase of different space-based *and* planet-based adventures.

> *Although the second season clocked good  ratings. Lost in Space
> underwent a format  change in its third and final season as the
> Jupiter 2 traveled to new worlds every week. The stories were more
> serious and gave more attention to other cast members. "It was felt
> there had been too much whimsy in the second year," says Duncan.
> "The result was  fewer scenes between family members, and  less
> interplay between Smith and the Robot.  There was also a lot more
> action, done at a  time when TV violence was the chief concern of
> social critics."*

There was significantly more action overall (this being reflected in the new start sequence and more exciting theme song) as well as the introduction of a traveling pod that would allow them to visit a different planet each week and props, alien costumes and spaceship models being regularly recycled between *Lost in Space* and *Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea*, creating the illusion of a larger budget.